# Getting individual values from an element in a List

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I currently have this and it works absolutely fine, just getting the values I don't understand.

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> snake = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
...
snake.Insert(0, Tuple.Create(x, y));
...
Console.Writeline(snake[5]);
```

Output ex: (5, 198)

-

How would I just get the x or the y value, such

```
Console.Writeline(snake[5][0]);
```

Would output 5

For example

Edit:

Nevermind found the answer

```
int sx = snake[Blength-1].Item1;
```

Comment: Tuples don't support indexers. You could use `int[2]`

Comment: [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386940.aspx) [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386892.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select which item you want by adding .Item#

```
snake[5].Item1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A tuple cannot be accessed through an indexer. You can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(snake[5].Item1); // Will output 5
```

If you want to access the second item, do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(snake[5].Item2); // Will output 198
```

Note: the maximum number of items that you can place in a single tuple is 8 by the way ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386921(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tuple.Item1, Tuple.Item2, etc. See the example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384265(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var tuple1 = Tuple.Create(12);
Console.WriteLine(tuple1.Item1);     // Displays 12
```